How to Disable Forced Password Change After First Login in Grafana Deployed via Helm?
I am deploying Grafana using the official Helm chart from https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts and want to disable the forced password change prompt that appears after the first login for the admin user.
I attempted to configure the following in the grafana.ini section to disable the password change prompt:
grafana.ini:
  auth:
    disable_login_form: false
    disable_signout_menu: true
    allow_user_sign_up: false
    allow_user_org_create: false

  users:
    allow_password_change: false

Is there a way to properly configure Grafana via Helm to completely disable this forced password change? Is there any other setting I need to adjust in the values.yaml file or any additional steps to ensure that the password change prompt does not appear?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I have not been able to figure this out yet, but please have an upvote.
